# Driving a 21 foot tow truck flat bed

Tags: usa, driving, permits

Driving a tow work in Louisiana and need to pick up a car in Mississippi, and bring back to Louisiana, do I need to stop at the weight station?

Comment: I’m not sure I see the connection between laws regarding the operation of a commercial vehicle to travel.

Comment: He's going to another state. I guess that counts as travel in the US.

Comment: @CGCampbell the weight of the cargo is not relevant to the GVWR, which depends on the maximum allowable weight of the cargo, not its actual weight.

Answer (score 0):

Think this may initiate a starting point for the answers you seek.

The abstract in quotes below alluding to International Registration Plan (IRP),  originates in the Mississippi Department of Transportation - Commercial Vehicle Enforcement Manual. On page 3, the second paragraph up from the bottom of the page.

"All states of the continental United States and Canadian provinces are members of the IRP. Vehicles that do not have IRP registrations and meet or exceed the limitations may secure a trip permit for the privilege of using the Mississippi highways. The twenty-five dollar trip permit or 72-hour permit may be obtained through the Jackson Permit Department or from the first weigh station upon entering the State.

http://mdot.ms.gov/documents/enforcement/Manuals/Commercial%20Motor%20Vehicle%20Manual.pdf